# Can C++ raise an error when std array initialization is too small?

Tags: c++, gcc, stdarray

Suppose I have an array of:

```
std::array<int, 6> {4,3,2};
```

Is it possible to raise an error or warning when this is the case? In some cases it might be useful to have this explicitly matching.

Comment: That should work like initializing a "normal" C-style plain array: The remaining values are "zero" initialized. So there's really nothing wrong with it.

Comment: My worries are mainly people initializing a wrong sized array and forgetting a number. I understand that the code is in no case wrong, only that there might be cases where you have a long array that you want to do some static assertion in a way to see if it is missing values.

Comment: you could create your own `init_with_all_elements` function, though then still nothing prevents you from calling the arrays constructor directly

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`std::make_array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/make_array) or something like it to cause the types to differ

```
std::array<int, 6> = std::make_array(4,3,2);
```

gives this error in gcc:

> `<source>:30:53: error: conversion from 'array<[...],3>' to non-scalar type 'array<[...],6>' requested`

Comment: How is support for this across the major toolchains? What version of GCC was that?

Answer (score 8):

You can create your own layer of abstraction that complains when you don't pass the exact same number of arguments for initialization.

```
template <std::size_t N, class ...Args>
auto createArray(Args&&... values)
{
   static_assert(sizeof...(values) == N);

   using First = std::tuple_element_t<0, std::tuple<Args...>>;

   return std::array<First, N>{values...};
}
```

To be invoked as

```
auto ok = createArray<6>(4, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1);

auto notOk = createArray<6>(4, 3, 2};
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of writing your own createArray method you can use the https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/make_array

if your compiler supports it.

```
#include <experimental/array>
int main()
{
    std::array<int,5> arr1= std::experimental::make_array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5); // ok
    std::array<int,3> arr2= std::experimental::make_array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5); // fails
    std::array<int,6> arr3= std::experimental::make_array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5); // fails
}
```

But everybody can directly init the array via constructor. So there is no guarantee for your code base if you don't check ( automatically ) against some coding guidelines.